# CSS not affecting that is written for IE browser only

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Why I am not able to apply an css that is for IE browser only,
I am trying to do it as below with in-page css block.

```
<style type="text/css">
    <!--[if IE]>
        body a {font-size:12px;text-decoration:none;}
    <![endif]-->
<style>
```

[Reference link](http://css-tricks.com/132-how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

Comment: if you're going to do IE-specific styles, you should be careful about which versions of IE they apply to -- IE9 is unlikely to need the same kind of hacks that IE8 and earlier needed.

Comment: @Spudley Yes, right but in my case I want it to apply for all the IE versions.  :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because conditional comments can't be in the style tag. Everything within `<style>` must be css. Try to wrap the style tag with the conditional comment.

**Your code:** http://jsbin.com/otidal/edit#preview

**Correct code:** http://jsbin.com/otidal/2/edit#preview

Answer (score 3):

The way to do it is around a css file reference,

**Example:**

```
<!--[if IE]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

You might be able to do this too:

```
<!--[if IE]>
     <style type="text/css">
        body a {font-size:12px;text-decoration:none;}
     <style>
<![endif]-->
```

But it has to be in the html page and not in a css file.